# How did Brud.Fyi link their custom domain to a Google Doc?

Tags: google-docs

How did Brud.fyi make their site a Google Doc? http://brud.fyi/

Point Nine did similar - http://pointnine.com/

[image: brud.fyi in desktop chrome browser]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. I posted an answer. If you need further help about how to use Google Docs, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

That is not a Google Docs feature but a HTML feature. Just take a look to the source code (right click over the page, then on the contextual menu choose View page source).

---

They are embedding a webpage inside another by using iframe, frameset HTML tags.

Resources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset